# What are some best monitoring tools available for mysql?

Tags: mysql, monitoring

I have a setup a linux mysql server and would like to monitor it. I found percona plugins for nagios and cacti. Are there any other tools available?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [MySQL Enterprise Monitor](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html)? Or are you only looking for freeware?

EDIT: You could also use this comparison chart from Wikipedia to pick one based on your needs:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems